# Customize hyperref package to only link references and not any other field like equations and tables

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

I am using `hyperref` package to internally link the references. The package automatically links equations, tables, and appendices as well. How can make it not to link any other field other than references?

Here is the MWE with the output,

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{moreverb} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{epsf} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{epstopdf} 
\usepackage{ctable} 
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
colorlinks=false,
citebordercolor= blue,
pagebackref=true,}

\begin{document}

\title{Hyperef customization}
\author{Ahmed Mahmood} 
\email{shahjee@kawan.desi}
\affiliation{Koocha-e-Dildaraan, Khazro, Pakistan}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
How to link internal fields in PDF document.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\appendix
\section{}\label{basis}
The parameters needed for the generation of the basis set used in this work, 
according      to the procedure explained in Ref. \cite{bohrvel}, are given 
in Table \ref{dzp}. The  parameters need to generate the pseudopotentials  
are listed in Equation \ref{pseudo}.

\begin{equation}
y=ax+b
\label{dzp}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 y=ax^2+bx+c
\label{pseudo}
\end{equation}

\bibliography{HinGe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I would like only the referees to be linked not the equations or email. And furthermore the references to be back linked as well in the bibliography.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. It works for all the fields which are referred using `\ref` command. It doesn't work for `\email{}` for example. Secondly how to back-link the bibliography?

Comment: @Mico As you can see I using revtex document class. `\texttt{...}` doesn't go very well with it. 
By back-link bibliography I mean as all the references are listed and numbered at the end of the document. When I click a particular references in bibliography I should be able to go the location in the document where it is cited.

Comment: I've posted an answer to address the issues you've raised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a cross-reference that's not also a hyperlink, use `\ref*` instead of `\ref`. Likewise, add an asterisk to commands such as `\eqref`, `\pageref`, and `\autoref`.

To get the command `\email` (which is provided by the `revtex4-1` document class) *not* to create a hyperlink, you need to modify the macro `\@email`, say by inserting the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@email#1#2{%
 \endgroup
 \@AF@join{#1\texttt{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

I do not believe it's possible to create hyperlinks from the entries in the references section *to the respective citation callouts* -- unless each and every entry is cited *once and only once*, a condition that's not usually true. I see that you're setting the option `pagebackref=true` when loading `hyperref`; this will provide a list of pages on which each entry is cited.

Comment: Thanks again. You are right that if each reference is cite multiple times which is usually the case then it would tricky to something such as links to citation callouts. However I have seen PDFs having this feature and clicking on the hyperlink takes you to where the reference is first cited. I am not how were those PDFs generated.

Comment: @R.U. - I guess I've seen links from article-type entries in published journal articles to online depositories where the original articles are available online. Speaking for myself, I've never seen links of the type you describe.